# Proper Way to Format SQL Query Within C# Application

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# console application that makes a bunch of queries to a database server.

I frequently need to modify the SQL and would like to simply copy/paste the SQL from my SQL Editor into my C# source without having to reformat the SQL every time.

Currently, the SQL is all on one line...  like below:

```
  OleDbDataAdapter da_ssm_servers = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Server;", connSSM);
```

The SQL is much longer than above with a lot of table JOINS, etc.

I would like to keep the formatting, but don't really want to have to go back and add quotes around each line, etc.

If anyone has any recommendations and examples, it would be appreciated.

Comment: It´s easier use Stored Procedures to separate the SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

Comment: I agree.   I'm using DB2 and this is a simple utility app and using SP would be overkill for me.  Plus, DB2 is not very user friendly.  Horrible product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT * 
    FROM mytable 
    ORDER BY Server";
OleDbDataAdapter da_ssm_servers = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connSSM);
```

Comment: Does the extra spacing,padding make any difference?  I'm using DB2 and it seems to be very sensitive with SQL syntax.   Hate it.

Comment: That may be db-specific. I have no experience with DB2. Try it and see.

Comment: I format my SQL statements like this too. They run fine against SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005. I have not run them against SQL Server 2008 but would expect the extra spacing not to have an effect.

Comment: Just be careful to not insert any <kbd>tab</kbd> /t characters in to the string as most databases will complain at run time.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to stay away from ad hoc queries like you are using and utilize **stored procedures**.  That would decouple your design, as well as limit your calls to a stored procedure name and possibly parameters.

But if you must use ad hoc queries then prefix with `@` and you will be able to span multiple lines without having to surround each line in quotes.

Comment: Thanks -- this app is a simple utility app to dump some stuf to a file so I can check into SVN for audit/change purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the @ syntax then you can have the SQL span multiple lines just fine.

For example

```
string sql = @"select 
                  colA, 
                  colB, 
                  colC
               from
                  tableX
                  inner join tableY
                     on tableX.colA = tableY.colA
               where
                  colB > 20;"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code should work fine.  When you start your string with @ then you're using a verbatim string.  Line breaks and formatting are preserved and you don't need to enclose each line in quotes.  You just need an ending quote.